# What does "while :; do" really do in bash?

Tags: bash

I see code like this:

```
while :; do
    #commands
done
```

Is that the same as

```
while :
do
    #commands
done
```

And is that just an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is a shell builtin `Null command`. You can type `help :` in the terminal:

```
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

It looks like `/bin/true`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is just an infinite loop.  You will typically find that code inside the `while` loop calls `break` to exit the loop when some condition is met.